# Windows 8 - No OS files found on disk

Tags: windows, windows-8, boot

I had a working version of Windows 8 but yesterday my notebook was crashed and became unresponsive so I had to make a reboot by its power switch.
After that, I wasn't able to reboot the notebook: the booting process now ends with a BSOD.
I've checked the log file under the `D:\Windows\System32\Logfiles\Srt\SrtTrail.txt` path, and it writes that:

```
 Root cause found: No OS files found on disk.
 Repair action: Partition table repair
 Result: failed. Error code = 0x490
```

Then I replaced my notebook's SSD with an older HDD, and the machine can boot from the HDD.

It seems to be that my SSD's boot information got corrupted, so I tried to use the `bootrec` tool to fix the booting - I tried to run it with all possible options, but nothing helped.
I found this "script" on the Windows support page:

```
bcdedit /export C:\BCD_Backup
c:
cd boot
attrib bcd -s -h -r
ren c:\boot\bcd bcd.old
bootrec /RebuildBcd
```

But this does not helps either.

Does anyone has a solution for this problem?

**Update:**

Can it be the error of the SSD? If it is, why doesn't the CheckDisk found any errors?